# SAM2 Web SSO Configuration is not opening JSPException while including path '/sso-saml/add_service_provider.jsp

Tags: wso2-identity-server

When configuring SAM2 with SSO, we are not able to proceed because of a configuration issue in the "Inbound Authentication Configuration" page. The log is showing as below:

[2020-12-03 13:04:28,617] ERROR - JspTilesRequestContext JSPException while including path '/sso-saml/add_service_provider.jsp'.
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException while including page.
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:102) ~[tiles-jsp_2.0.5.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88) [tiles-jsp_2.0.5.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82) [tiles-jsp_2.0.5.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465) [tiles-jsp_2.0.5.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140) [tiles-jsp_2.0.5.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117) [tiles-jsp_2.0.5.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171) [tiles-jsp_2.0.5.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75) [tiles-jsp_2.0.5.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80) [tiles-jsp_2.0.5.wso2v1.jar:?]
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:780) [hc_2077817849/:?]
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:443) [hc_2077817849/:?]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]

Comment: Could you please mention the IS version that you are currently working on?

Comment: @Prakash according to your logs in the comment, it seems you are using WSO2 Identity Server-5.10.0. Do you encounter this issue after doing any configurations to a service provider's SAML SSO configs or the very first time when trying to open the SAML SSO config page?  also, have you patched any customizations related to SAML ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using API Manager server (Not the Identity Server). WSO2 API Manager doesn't support SAML Inbound Authentication. Hence you are seeing an error trying to add SAML configurations.
If you want to SSO SAML applications, you might have to use WSO2 Identity Server or any alternative.

P.S. Management Console may contain the SAML option for Inbound Authentication as it is using the same component as in the Identity Server. But will throw an error upon trying to edit. Therefore, please stick to the alternative

[IS Documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/extensions/saml2-sso/configuring-identity-server-as-idp-for-sso/)

Comment: I am using th Identidy Server only. Please see the log text [2020-12-04 13:45:51,815] []  INFO {openjpa.jdbc.JDBC} - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.H2Dictionary" (H2 1.4.199 (2019-03-13) ,H2 JDBC Driver 1.4.199 (2019-03-13)).
[2020-12-04 13:45:51,906] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Server           :  WSO2 Identity Server-5.10.0
[2020-12-04 13:45:51,907] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - WSO2 Carbon started in 52 sec